# cocos2d exit code - 1 build error

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js, build-error

I have been researching this error for days now and I haven't figure it out yet. I'm working in cocos2d javascript and when trying to build my game I get this error

> Failed to create project with exitCode-1

I am making a space invaders type game and I have no noticeably syntax errors but I'm still getting this build error. Any help? Here are some photos of the issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8LEN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrPiA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need install 
- NDK
- ANT
- SDK
and set path in preference